# Aggregate two columns to be in new column and if there are two NaN in both column, the new column should give NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I want to aggregate two columns to be in new column. There are possibilities that the two columns will include NaN value. The table looks like below:

```
no   type   status   category
1     a       xx        yy   
2     b       xx        nan
3     c       nan       nan
```

What I have tried so far was aggregate them by using this following script. But it also combines two NaN become NaN_NaN

```
df['category'] = df[['cat_1', 'cat_2']].astype(str).agg('_'.join, axis = 1)
```

The expected result is if there are two NaNs, the new column will only give NaN to the new column instead of NaN_NaN

```
no   type   cat_1      cat_2    category  
1     a       xx        yy        xx_yy
2     b       xx        nan       xx_nan
3     c       nan       nan        nan
```

Comment: are the columns names wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
df["category"] = df[["cat_1","cat_2"]].astype(str).agg(lambda x: '_'.join(set(x)), 1)
```

Or equivalently:

```
df["category"] = df[["cat_1","cat_2"]].astype(str).agg(set, 1).agg('_'.join)
```

**Output** (in both cases)

```
df
   no type cat_1 cat_2 category
0   1    a    xx    yy    xx_yy
1   2    b    xx   NaN   nan_xx
2   3    c   NaN   NaN      nan
```